# Ciertas conjugaciones verbales no convencionales

Tags: verbos, participio, formas-irregulares

He escuchado algunas veces a personas conjugar los siguientes verbos de la siguiente manera (entre paréntesis la forma correcta):

Morir → morido (muerto)

Volver → volvido (vuelto)

Resolver → resolvido (resuelto)

Y otros verbos más que en el momento no tengo a  mano. ¿Usar esa conjugación se considera un error gravísimo? Yo he escuchado frecuentemente esta conjugación en algunos lugares de Perú, y también me han hecho saber que se puede escuchar en ciertos lugares de Ecuador y Bolivia, los países andinos. ¿Es posible hablar en este caso de un dialecto y, por consiguiente, se podría tolerar esa  conjugación?

Y una pregunta aparte, que también de alguna manera tiene que ver con el asunto, ¿alguien tiene datos de la génesis de esa conjugación? Es decir, ¿en qué circunstancia apareció esta manera de hablar? Y, para terminar, ¿el uso de esta conjugación es también común en otros países de Latinoamérica o en España?

Comment: Supongo que mucha gente de la región andina será bilingüe, hablando su idioma tradicional en familia y en su pueblo, pero con la necesidad de hablar español en otros ámbitos.  Me imagino que estos pequeños errores surgieron así, y luego se habrían extendido a más gente con el tiempo.  Ciertamente en México muchos campesinos tienen sus anomalías en el lenguaje, a pesar de que gran parte de la gente del campo hoy día es unilingüe.  Ciertos variantes de los verbos y otras cosas ya forman parte de la cultura campesina.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sólo hay, actualmente, tres casos de participios que se admiten en su forma regular e irregular: Imprimido/Impreso, Freído/Frito, Proveído/Provisto.

Fuente: [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/dobles-participios-imprimidoimpreso-freidofrito-proveidoprovisto)

Sobre el origen de las conjugaciones irregulares, puedes leer un artículo interesante que estudia el origen de las irregularidades en los verbos del idioma español:
[El concepto de verbo irregular en la gramática
del siglo de oro](http://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/RFRM/article/viewFile/RFRM9696110061A/12069), por Francisco Javier Satorre Grau.

Comment: Al menos como parte de un verbo compuesto, son precisamente estos con *sofreído/sofrito* que es un derivado.  También hay unos pocos otros (como *pagado ~ pago*) que solo se admite en los contextos no compuestos y que a veces se ve en la poesía.

Comment: Cierto, pero pago no actúa como participio, sino como adverbio, y lo mismo podría decirse de sofrito en cierto modo.

Comment: Tal vez sirva esta pareja, no estoy seguro: una persona _vuelta_ contra la pared, una persona _volteada_ contra la pared.

Comment: @Rodrigo `Vuelto/a` es el participio de `Volver`, mientras que `Volteado/a` es el participio de `Voltear`. Personalmente creo que en lugar de `vuelta contra la pared` debe usarse `volteada contra la pared`, en el sentido de "girada", reservando "vuelta" para aquello que presupone una "ida".

Comment: Comenté mal.  Parece que la RAE *sí* acepta *pago*.  Del DPD: «En el español general actual el participio es *pagado*.  Pero en gran parte de América pervive en el uso coloquial el antiguo participio irregular *pago*, normalmente en función adjetiva». En el DRAE, se registra el participio como «pagado, pago». En la gramática (§4.12k) se incluye también *prender* (preso), *elegir* (electo), aunque se desaconseja su uso en tiempos compuestos sin desaconsejarlo en construcciones pasivas. En §4.12n, hay una lista de los participios antiguos considerados solo como adjetivos hoy (conquisto, espeso…)

Comment: Tambien hay confundido/confuso

Comment: @dockeryz Confuso es adjetivo (fue participio antiguamente). Prueba a decir "Las palabras me han `confuso`" comparado con "Estoy `confundido` por las palabras".

Answer (score 8):

Sí, es un error.

Yo aprendí inglés británico, con lo cual usaba *learnt* como participio de "learn". Ahora vivo en Estados Unidos y esa gente favorece el uso de *learned*, como si fuera regular en lugar de regular. Sin embargo, creo que no hay dialectos del español que favorezcan esas conjugaciones, conjugando el verbo irregular como regular.

Sí que es cierto que suele haber bastante confusión en general con el uso de algunas formas como "impreso vs. imprimido", "frito vs. freído" y similares. Yo no he oído muchos "moridos" ni "volvidos", pero sí bastantes "conducí" (en lugar de *conduje*), por ejemplo.

A todos se nos puede escapar algunas veces estas meteduras de pata, pero no son formas correctas en ningún dialecto.

Comment: Y al revés, hemos innovado formas irregulares como para *dive* -> *dived* en-GB, *dove* en-US :-)

Answer (score 3):

Esas formas son incorrectas, ni siquiera están en la RAE.
Así que hay que usarlas como corresponde.
De hecho suena bastante mal decir **devolvido** en vez de **devuelto.**

Answer (score 2):

Parece que no hay un patrón regular: cual forma se usa en cual contexto depende del verbo si mismo (y también del dialecto, región etc):

> Con esta investigación teníamos como objetivo estudiar las diferencias gramaticales y de uso entre los dobles participios en el español actual, centrando el interés en las dos formas participiales de los verbos *bendecir, freír, imprimir* y *corromper*. Después de nuestros análisis, hemos constatado que **ninguna de las dos teorías mayores –el lexicalismo y el construccionismo– pueden explicar de forma sistemática las diferencias en español actual.** La hipótesis de que los participios que muestran irregularidad son fruto de reglas léxicas o de una asociación directa entre una raíz y un nudo funcional no puede dar cuenta de los casos en que el participio en cuestión se comporta como verbal, y tampoco explica con facilidad los casos en que el participio regular –que se espera sea fruto de una regla sintáctica o de una asociación entre una estructura verbal y el morfema de participio– se puede comportar como un adjetivo. **Parece que en cada verbo, el par de participios se diferencia por propiedades diferentes en cada caso, lo cual sugiere que el problema debe ser enfocado para cada verbo en particular.**
>
> - [*Los dobles participios en español: Estudio de corpus*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/19640960.pdf) (2013)

Comment: @Perapera tiene más sentido ahora?